# Differentiate between different types of...: is it acceptable in written English?

Tags: repetition, roots

Would be acceptable in written (academic paper) English to write "Differentiate between different types of ...". I once was harshly criticized when I wrote in the paper:  "Participants experienced the experience of ...".

Many thanks.

Comment: No, "differentiate different" should be OK.  But note: Use "between" only if there are just two types, and use "among" if there are more than two.

Comment: even if it is acceptable, it might be better to phrase it "Differentiate between various types of ..."

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable, but redundant. If you're asked to differentiate between things, the obvious assumption is that the things are different, so it's not necessary to say so explicitly. You can just write "Differentiate between types of ..."